# How to use transaction by sequelize in my node js

Tags: sql, node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

While converting legacy long sql procedure to sequelizer, I met trouble to make transaction to my async functions.

I read sequelizer's transaction documents.  But failed to understand clearly.

Here is my code.

```
const models = require('../models/models.js');
const sequelize = models.Sequelize;


async function isExistFeeHist(dansokSeqNo) {
  log.debug("isExistFeeHist()");
  let feeHist = await models.FeeHist.findOne({  
    where: { 
      DansokSeqNo: dansokSeqNo,
      FeeStatus: {[Op.ne]: null}, //is not null
      DelYN: false
    }
  });
  return !!feeHist;
}

async function isPaid(dansokSeqNo) {
  ...
}

async function getNextDansokHistSerialNo(dansokSeqNo) {
  ...
}

async function getVBankSeqNo(dansokSeqNo) {
  ...                
}

async function updateVBankList(dansokSeqNo, vBankSeqNo) {
  ...
}

//check if can cancel
async function checkCancelable(dansokSeqNo) {
  log.debug("checkCancelable() ", dansokSeqNo);

  if (await isExistFeeHist(dansokSeqNo)) {
    let e = {status:400, message: 'already imposed dansokSeqNo ' + dansokSeqNo };
    return Promise.reject({status:400, message: e.message });
  }

  if (await isPaid(dansokSeqNo)) {
    let e = {status:400, message: 'already paid dansokSeqNo ' + dansokSeqNo };
    return Promise.reject({status:400, message: e.message });
  }

  return Promise.resolve();
}

....

async function doCancel(dansokSeqNo, cancelCauseCode, histMemo) {

  try {
    await checkCancelable(dansokSeqNo); 

    //// <== Here I want to start transaction

    let nextDansokSerialNo =  await getNextDansokHistSerialNo(dansokSeqNo);
    let dansokHist = await insertNewDansokHist(dansokSeqNo, nextDansokSerialNo, cancelCauseCode, histMemo);
    await updateDansokHist(dansokSeqNo, cancelCauseCode);
    let vBankSeqNo = await getVBankSeqNo(dansokSeqNo);
    if (vBankSeqNo > 0) {
      await updateVBankList(dansokSeqNo, vBankSeqNo);
      let vBankList = await getVBankList(dansokSeqNo);
    }

    // <== Here I want to commit transaction
  } catch (e) {
    // <== Here I want to rollback transaction
    return Promise.reject({status:e.status, message: e.message });
  }
}

exports.cancelDansok = function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
  ...
  jwtAcessAuth(accessToken)
  .then((decoded) => {
    log.info("jwt success, ", decoded);
    worker = decoded.loginName;
    return doCancel(dansokSeqNo, cancelCauseCode, histMemo);
  })
  .then(() => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'cancelDansok success.' });
  })
  .catch(e => {
    return res.status(e.status).json(e);
  });
};
```

My function is assembled with several async functions.  And it need to bind one transaction.

What is the best practice to use transaction in my several async await functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best example provided by Sequlize for Transaction :

All you need to care is pass `transaction` to next level of chaining

```
return sequelize.transaction(function (t) {

  // chain all your queries here. make sure you return them.
  return User.create({
    firstName: 'Abraham',
    lastName: 'Lincoln'
  }, {transaction: t}).then(function (user) {
    return user.setShooter({
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Boothe'
    }, {transaction: t});
  });

}).then(function (result) {
  // Transaction has been committed
  // result is whatever the result of the promise chain returned to the transaction callback
}).catch(function (err) {
  // Transaction has been rolled back
  // err is whatever rejected the promise chain returned to the transaction callback
});
```

For more details : **[Transactions](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/transactions.html)**

Comment: Why the return at the start ?

Comment: (it can be misleading). sequelize.transaction return a promise. In the above snippet it's the auto managed form. If it resolve (then) then it's committed, if not (rejected) [catch] then it's rolledback. The return above mean nothing. Unless we want to passe the promise as per making our transaction in a function. And then we use the function, or export it ...etc